# Automatically call a phone number when a WhatsApp message from a certain contact is received

Tags: api, triggers, twilio, whatsapp

Anyone know how one could realize this?

Maybe via the Twilio API? (https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp)

I'd also be more than happy to pay for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this with Twilio if the initial phone number receiving the message is a Twilio Number.

If a Twilio Number is receiving the WhatsApp Message you can trigger a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) to initiate a call using [Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api).